# How to squash a bunch of commits without merge conflicts? (I only care about current state for the squash)

Tags: git

For some context, I have a journal I keep using markdown files, synced across devices using OneDrive. Because OneDrive sometimes does dumb things regarding file conflicts, I back up the journal to git with a script that pushes a backup commit every 5 minutes. To keep the number of commits from growing too numerous, every week or 2 I squash all the automated commits into a single snapshot commit. Also note that I don't have any branches other than master, everything just happens on this one branch.

So currently my commit history looks like snapshot1, snapshot2, ... snapshot X, autocommit 1, autocommit 2, ... autocommit Y. I want it to be come snapshot1 ... snapshot X+1, so I started doing my usual routine of `git rebase --root -i` and then marking all the auto commits for squash. But then during the rebase, I get a ton of merge conflicts. No idea why this is happening, this hasn't happened before. My guess is somewhere down the line, OneDrive did something weird and I must've committed the changes, perhaps I had a merge conflict that I manually handled a while back that I don't remember.

What I would like is that whatever the current state of my repo is now becomes snapshot X+1, and all the auto commits since the last snapshot just get squashed into snapshot X+1 (i.e. I don't care how files changes in the meantime, as long as the final result is the current state of the repo).

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I don't want to manually resolve merge conflicts (I actually tried this method and at some point the files got messed up and post-rebase it didn't reflect what the current state of the repo was).

Comment: Choose one: (1) Use OneDrive. (2) Use Git. Never do both in the same directory. Your observed problems look like a consequence of using both.

Comment: For a native journaling + markdown + git experience there is [Dendron](https://wiki.dendron.so/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for *why* you're getting merge conflicts, this is likely the reason:

> perhaps I had a merge conflict that I manually handled a while back that I don't remember.

It appears that your history is a bunch of "snapshot" commits which you wish to keep, followed by a bunch of automated commits which you wish to squash. You're probably just rebasing back too far, all the way to root instead of to the last good commit. So for example:

```
# instead of:
git rebase --root -i


# try:
git rebase snapshot-X -i
```

That should solve it, or, assuming the commits you wish to squash are all the latest commits in your graph (i.e. there are no commits after them that you wish to keep as separate commits), another more efficient way to squash is:

```
git switch your-branch
git reset --soft snapshot-X
git commit -m "Your message here"
```

This will squash all of the commits after `snapshot-X` into a single commit, without the inefficiency of the interactive rebase doing it one commit at a time.

Comment: Yeah the issue was somewhere in the automated commits was a merge conflict that was handled manually so rebasing (even from snapshot-X) wasn't working, but the soft reset did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @ROODAY good to hear. Btw, I'd be weary of an automated process resolving merge conflicts by itself, unless you know in advance exactly what the resolution would be...